# How do you downgrade Android Studio build-tools?

Tags: android-studio, nativescript

I'm trying to downgrade my version of Android Studio's build-tools from 33 to 32 because NativeScript isn't compatible with 33, but I don't know how. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Check "Show Package Details" in bottom right > Uncheck the newer versions you want uninstalled

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modify the project build.gradle file,compileSdkVersion from 33 to 32,buildToolsVersion from "33.0.0" to "32.0.0",targetSdkVersion from 33 to 32